# fullCalendar - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am populating all the months on a page, for example:

```
<?php foreach(range(0,11) as $month): ?>
      <div style='float:left; width:303px;' id='calenderSalesMonth_<?php echo $month ?>' class='calenderSales'></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`fullCalendar` should set specific month via `id='calenderSalesMonth_*'` and it would not work, I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`

Code:

```
$('.calenderSales').fullCalendar({
       editable: false,
       events:  { url: 'calender-events.php' },
       firstDay:1,
       month: $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1],
       year: 2013
});
```

Comment: if `.attr("id")` returns undefined, you can't call `.split` on it because `.split` is a method of the String object and can't be called on undefined.

Comment: Is this code inside some `click` event handler?

Comment: @dfsq No.. it is not.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back try it using `.prop()`

Comment: @DipeshParmar `.attr("id")`  return `Unexpected identifier ` - not sure what the solution now... ?

Answer (score 1):

User `month` global variable and then set it.

```
var month = $('.calenderSales').attr("id").split("_")[1];

$('.calenderSales').fullCalendar({
       editable: false,
       events:  { url: 'calender-events.php' },
       firstDay:1,
       month: month,
       year: 2013
});
```

**OR**

use `.prop()` its `.attr()` alternative.

**OR**

Try to wrap code inside `$(window).load(function());`

Comment: Declaring a global `month` variable is not going to work because I have many months on a page, for example: `calenderSales_0`, `calenderSales_1` , `calenderSales_2`

Comment: Upgraded jQuery, `prop` wont work. same error..  `month:  $(this).prop("id").split("_")[1],`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back hey bro working on your problem..do not loose you temper by down-voting me...